# Automate initialization of SAP B1 "Analytics Services" for tenant

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, sapb1

I would like to automate actions over SAP Analytics Services, especially Initialize Analytic Services on tenants.

[image: SAP Cloud control center]

Analytics Services run on https://analytics-server:40000/Enablement using SAML2 SSO to authenticate, where I'm stuck on generating SAMLresponse

My question is if there is some way (command line, PowerShell,...), how to initialize Analytics Service for Tenant programmatically.

or simplified how to authenticate to https://analytics-server:40000/Enablement programatically

Comment: Have you seen this blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2012/10/17/request-adfs-security-token-with-powershell/

Comment: I played with that but looks like a dead end or I have not enough knowledge to get it work